# Blender Viewport Not moving correctly

Tags: 3d-view

So I noticed that my friend has the same view settings as me, but he can move his view freely and I can't;

GYAZO1 1: his view https://gyazo.com/9f53fbb76a00def58aa31350973ad501

Gyazo 2: mine https://gyazo.com/5c4605b5b2adc48b2c7180922a55f06f

I've tried Clip -> start : 0
but that is not that good to view because some things get transparent.

Comment: Please use the built-in uploader for images or gifs. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: The Clip End can be increased to render more of the scene in depth. But, as a rule, when you increase the end the Clip start should be increased by the same factor, so when you increase the End by 10 times, the Start should also be increased with 10 times. This to prevent artefacts you encountered when zeroing out the Start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your Origin Point is mis-placed. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and your Origin Point will be reset to Default place.

> i've tried Clip -> start : 0 but that is not that good to view bc some
>   things get transparent

Pressing 0 gives you the Camera Perspective.

> Also this may be because you are too close to your mesh, as your friend's
>   view is quite far.

Comment: even if i zoom out it will do the same :(
it wont let me do the same as the 1st gyazo

Comment: Have you tried shift + c

Comment: even if i zoom in on my friends mesh he can still move it around with nothing vanishing.
yes ive tried : https://gyazo.com/473f120e30b0ff0f5df5be577b3b2663

Comment: If you had tried that keyboard shortcut your origin point should be at the center of the viewport which is not showing in the video you linked.

Comment: i pressed shift + c and that's what happends. it sends me to nothing :(

Comment: Can you attach your file.

Comment: how do i do it ? :(

Comment: Upload it to your google drive and link it in your question

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ULLHCKjBMHxeA4gvggP5HzX6lDX-zEOB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I checked your file, there's nothing wrong in there.

Comment: well i cant move like the 1st gyazo without thing vanishing from screen

Comment: It's already having that type of movement, what's left now?

Comment: thats the only thing that i wasnt able to do. you did nothing ??

Comment: I think you should try re-checking the file you sent, because I didn't spot any issues you are asking about.